# Typescript "declaration merging" does not work if there is an "import x = require("x");"

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2015

The ["declaration merging"](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#declaration-merging) in Typescript means that "the compiler is doing the work of merging two separate declarations declared with the same name into a single definition."

However, I encounter a situation which I have no idea why these 2 interface declarations could not be merged.

(The environment is "visual studio 2015 community" + "Node.js Tools for Visual Studio" (made by Microsoft, too))

Firstly, there is a file named 'b.ts' where you can put anything into it, just make sure b.ts acks as a module (eg., have at least one export declaration). And another file named 'a.ts', the content of it is as follows:

b.ts

```
export var c;
```

a.ts

```
import a = require("b");

// ErrorConstructor is declared in the lib.d.ts from "Node.js Tools for Visual Studio". 
//
// interface ErrorConstructor {
//   new (message?: string): Error;
//   (message?: string): Error;
//   prototype: Error;
// }
//
// However, it lacks the prepareStackTrace property, so I added it, and 
// expect typescript could 'merge' this one with the original one.

interface ErrorConstructor {
    prepareStackTrace: any;
}

function test() {
    var a = Error.prepareStackTrace; // The typescript complains that
                                     // Property 'prepareStackTrace' does not 
                                     // exist on type 'ErrorConstructor'.
}
```

As you can see in the comments, typescript compiler complains that 'Error.prepareStackTrace' does not exist.

However, if I comment out the "import a = require("b")" line, the error has gone!

```
//import a = require("b");

interface ErrorConstructor {
    prepareStackTrace: any;
}

function test() {
    var a = Error.prepareStackTrace;  // <-- no error!
}
```

I have no idea why typescript could not perform the declaration merging if there is an "import x = require("x");". Could anyone help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

> If you have an import or an export at the root level of a TypeScript file then it creates a local scope within that file

Comment: Thx! This is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2821#issuecomment-94093212

"by adding import or export to the top level scope in your file, you are truing this file into a module."

I thought if there is at least one 'export', then the file would becoming a module (Because Typescript compiler would generate a function to wrap the file content). But, through that comment, if there is at least one 'import', the file would becoming a module, too.